# Como contar toques (letras, espaços e símbolos) em PHP?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, acentuação

Eu fiz um programa que extrai minhas anotações do meu código e cria um arquivo `txt` para ser um manualzinho. Fiz uma formatação para ficar mais legal:

```
+-----------+
|           |
| ESPECIAIS |
|           |
+-----------+
```

Ele pega a linha ESPECIAIS e formata. Simples! Ocorre que alguns não ficam bem formatados porque tem letras com acento, e neste caso não consigo contar os toques corretamente. A linha "FUNÇÕES" fica assim:

```
+-----------+
|           |
| FUNÇÕES |
|           |
+-----------+
```

Isso porque a string é formada pelos códigos `70|85|78|195|135|195|149|69|83` somando 9 caracteres pelo `strlen` do PHP, já que os acentos estão usando o prefixo 195, extrapolando a contagem em 2.

Este problema em específico não é difícil de resolver, mas quero aproveitar para compreender melhor a questão. Não sei como funciona a codificação dos acentos nesse caso (arquivo de texto UTF-8).

Em JavaScript eu conto os toques usando `DOMElement.textContent.lenght` que já compreende a *string* como texto.

Existe alguma função similar em PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solução mais simples é usar a função [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) que está preparada para lidar com caracteres *multibyte* como é o caso do UTF-8.

```
mb_strlen("FUNÇÕES") // produz 7
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/KFPstr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/irtkgaxb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/Mblen.php).

Comment: Não estava funcionando. Como respondeste com tanta segurança, resolvi tentar de novo. Desta vez eu forcei o UTF-8 no segundo parâmetro do mb_strlen, que é opcional - funcionou! Às vezes eu defino o conjunto de caracteres no início do arquivo php, desta vez eu não fiz, talvez seja isso. De qualquer forma, é bom o cara estar atento a este detalhe. Valeu!